# Recorrer una fila de select de una tabla con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy tratando de recorrer una tabla la cual en cada casilla tiene `select`, los cuales lo uso para calcular una suma, mi problema es como puedo obtener el valor de los `td`, ya que de recorrerlo si lo logro, pero no sé como puedo tomar dicho valor de los `select` de un `td`.

Codigo tr de mi tabla:

```
 <tr class="fila0" style="background: white;">                                          
  <td>
    <?php 
        echo $procesos[1];
        $i++;
    ?>
  </td>     
  <?php 
    $i=0;
    $dato=$objCriterio->listar_criterio($idEmpresa,$idUnidadNegocio);
    foreach ($dato as $criterio) { 
      $idCriterio=$criterio[0];
      $p=$criterio[4];
    ?>
    <td>
      <select id="OBJ<?php echo $idCriterio;?>" name="COE" onchange="FunSumT('OBJ'+<?php echo $idCriterio;?>,<?php echo $p ;?>);">
        <option value='0'>0</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  <?php $i++;} ?>   
   <?php 
    $i=0;
    $dato=$objProceso->listar_Proceso($idUnidadNegocio);
    foreach ($dato as $procesos) { ?>
      <td id="total<?php echo $i;?>"></td>
    <?php $i++;}  ?>              
</tr>
```

Codigo de JS

```
var tam=$('.fila0 td').length;
if(acum=="")
  acum=0;
$('.fila0 td').each(function(i){
if(i>0 && i<tam-1){
  // parseInt(suma.options[suma.selectedIndex].value)*p
  console.log($(this).html());
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices querer obtener los valores de los `select`? ¿Te refieres a obtener los valores de cada elemento seleccionado, o de todos los elementos? La pregunta no es clara, se agradecería que seas más específico.

Comment: Hola, disculpa por la tardanza. Me refiero a obtener los valores seleccionados de un select por ejemplo una casilla puede tener el valor de 1 seleccionado, otra de 2, otra de 0...

Comment: O sea, ¿quieres obtener los valores de los `select` seleccionados que hay en diferentes celdas de la `tablaX` y sumar esos valores?

Comment: Así es, abajo me comentaron una solucion a la cual llegue tambien. Por cierto mi duda ahora va, si es posible enviar un array php mediante Onclick de un td a una funcion de js y leerlo.

Comment: Te escribí otra forma de hacerlo, usando Javascript puro. Aunque vi que ya resolviste este problema. En cuanto a tu otra duda, este sitio funciona **por preguntas**. Lo correcto es que si tienes otra duda la plantees en otra pregunta diferente, explicando lo más claro posible el problema e indicando el código que has intentado.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque parece que ya lo resolviste, te dejo esta otra posibilidad usando Javascript puro, mediante el uso de `querySelectorAll`.

Se trata de recoger todos los `select` de la tabla, a la que previamente le has dado el nombre de una *clase*  para identificarla (puedes usar otro indentificador).

Luego sumas los valores en un acumulador.

```js
var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btnEnviar");

btnEnviar.onclick = function() {
  /*Acumulador*/
  var totalValue = 0;
  /*Seleccionamos todos los select de los elementos con la clase mi-tabla*/
  var allSelect = document.querySelector(".mi-tabla").querySelectorAll("select");

  /*Recorremos los select para sumar los valores*/
  allSelect.forEach(function(item) {
    /*Hay que parsear el valor a entero base 10*/ 
    totalValue += parseInt(item.value, 10);
  });
  console.log("El total es: " + totalValue);


}
```

```html
<table class="mi-tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="col1">
        <option value="0">--Seleccione celda 1--</option>
        <option value="1" selected>Uno</option>
        <option value="2">Dos</option>
        <option value="3">Tres</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="col2">
        <option value="0">--Seleccione celda 2--</option>
        <option value="1">Uno</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Dos</option>
        <option value="3">Tres</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="col3">
        <option value="0">--Seleccione celda 3--</option>
        <option value="1">Uno</option>
        <option value="2">Dos</option>
        <option value="3" selected>Tres</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnEnviar">Calcular</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

te puedo recomendar que la tabla la incluyas dentro de un formulario, posteriormente cuando quieras recorrer los valores de los elementos en su interior, ya sean inputs,select,textarea, etc...

los puedes rescatar con jQuery, ejemplo :

```
$('form').serialize()
```

añado link de librería para su conocimiento: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

suerte!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumValue = 0,
     $this;
$('.fila0 td').each(function(i){
    $this = $(this)
    $("option",$this).each(function (index, element) {
        sumValue += $(this).attr("value") // Obtiene values
        sumValue += $(this).html() // Obtiene valor dentro del select
    });
})
```

En caso  de que requieras todos los valores dentro del select